# mock useDispatch in jest and test the params with using that dispatch action in functional component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme

Hi I am writing test for functional component using the jest and enzyme. and When I simulate a click then params(state of component using useState) of component change. and when state is changed then useEffect call and in useEffect I am dispatching some asynchronous actions with params after changed. So I want to test params with I am dispatching the action. for this I want to mock dispatch. How can I achieve this ?
Anyone can help me, thanks in advance. Below I am sharing the code.

**component.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { clientOperations, clientSelectors } from '../../store/clients';
import Breadcrumb from '../../components/UI/Breadcrumb/Breadcrumb.component';
import DataTable from '../../components/UI/DataTable/DataTable.component';
import Toolbar from './Toolbar/Toolbar.component';

const initialState = {
  search: '',
  type: '',
  pageNo: 0,
  rowsPerPage: 10,
  order: 'desc',
  orderBy: '',
  paginated: true,
};

const Clients = ({ history }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const totalElements = useSelector(state => state.clients.list.totalElements);
  const records = useSelector(clientSelectors.getCompaniesData);
  const [params, setParams] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(clientOperations.fetchList(params));
  }, [dispatch, params]);

  function updateParams(newParams) {
    setParams(state => ({
      ...state,
      ...newParams,
    }));
  }

  function searchHandler(value) {
    updateParams({
      search: value,
      pageNo: 0,
    });
  }

  function typeHandler(event) {
    updateParams({
      type: event.target.value,
      pageNo: 0,
    });
  }

  function reloadData() {
    setParams(initialState);
  }

  const columns = {
    id: t('CLIENTS_HEADING_ID'),
    name: t('CLIENTS_HEADING_NAME'),
    abbrev: t('CLIENTS_HEADING_ABBREV'),
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Breadcrumb items={[{ title: 'BREADCRUMB_CLIENTS' }]}>
        <Toolbar
          search={params.search}
          setSearch={searchHandler}
          type={params.type}
          setType={typeHandler}
          reloadData={reloadData}
        />
      </Breadcrumb>
      <DataTable
        rows={records}
        columns={columns}
        showActionBtns={true}
        deletable={false}
        editHandler={id => history.push(`/clients/${id}`)}
        totalElements={totalElements}
        params={params}
        setParams={setParams}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

**Component.test.js**

```
const initialState = {
  clients: {
    list: {
      records: companies,
      totalElements: 5,
    },
  },
  fields: {
    companyTypes: ['All Companies', 'Active Companies', 'Disabled Companies'],
  },
};

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStoreConfigure = configureMockStore(middlewares);
const store = mockStoreConfigure({ ...initialState });

const originalDispatch = store.dispatch;
store.dispatch = jest.fn(originalDispatch)

// configuring the enzyme we can also configure using Enjym.configure
configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Clients ', () => {
  let wrapper;

  const columns = {
    id: i18n.t('CLIENTS_HEADING_ID'),
    name: i18n.t('CLIENTS_HEADING_NAME'),
    abbrev: i18n.t('CLIENTS_HEADING_ABBREV'),
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };
    wrapper = mount(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Clients history={historyMock} />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
  });

 it('on changing the setSearch of toolbar should call the searchHandler', () => {
    const toolbarNode = wrapper.find('Toolbar');
    expect(toolbarNode.prop('search')).toEqual('')
    act(() => {
      toolbarNode.props().setSearch('Hello test');
    });
    toolbarNode.simulate('change');
****here I want to test dispatch function in useEffect calls with correct params"**
    wrapper.update();
    const toolbarNodeUpdated = wrapper.find('Toolbar');
    expect(toolbarNodeUpdated.prop('search')).toEqual('Hello test')



  })

});
```

Comment: Can I call store.dispatch?
It's an anti-pattern to interact with the store directly in a React component, whether it's an explicit import of the store or accessing it via context (see the Redux FAQ entry on store setup for more details). Let React Redux’s connect handle the access to the store, and use the dispatch it passes to the props to dispatch actions.

Comment: @sid7747 that's how to do it with mapStateToProps and mapDispatch. Using hooks you are putting them directly in the component. After using those I'm though leaning towards having intermmediate connect layer or a intermmediate data component using hooks, so it's easier to test in isolation.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[upd] I've changed my mind dramatically since then. Now I think mocking store(with `redux-mock-store` or even real store that changes its state) - and wrapping component with `<Provider store={mockedStore}>` - is way more reliable and convenient. Check another answer below.

if you mock `react-redux` you will be able to verify arguments for `useDispatch` call. Also in such a case you will need to re-create `useSelector`'s logic(that's really straightforward and actually you don't have to make mock be a hook). Also with that approach you don't need mocked store or `<Provider>` at all.

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'; 

const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useSelector: jest.fn(),
  useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
}));

it('loads data on init', () => {
  const mockedDispatch = jest.fn();
  useSelector.mockImplementation((selectorFn) => selectorFn(yourMockedStoreData));
  useDispatch.mockReturnValue(mockedDispatch);
  mount(<Router><Clients history={historyMock} /></Router>);
  expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/*arguments your expect*/);
});
```

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion but I am unable to mount the component using this. giving an error **TypeError: _reactRedux.useSelector.mockImplementation is not a function**

Comment: have you put both `jest.mock(...` and `import ... from 'react-redux'` into your test file?

Comment: Yes I have put both.

Comment: added description on using factoring callback for mocks

Comment: `jest.mock('react-redux');

useDispatch.mockImplementation(() => store.dispatch)
useSelector.mockImplementation(() => { });

it('loads data on init', () => {
  const historyMock = { push: jest.fn() };
  let wrapper;
  wrapper = mount(<Router><Clients history={historyMock} /></Router>);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});`

by using this react-redux is mock, but how to provide data from useSelector ?

If I don't mock useDispatch.mockImplementation(() => store.dispatch) by using this approach then its giving error like dispatch is not a function.

Comment: oh, right. missed that you should get result of `useDispatch`, check update

Comment: **Thanks** @skyboyer your suggestion is working. I have successfully mocked the react-redux. but still unable to test 

``` expect(useDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(/*arguments your expect*/);

 expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function```

Any suggestion for this So I can test dispatching params.

Comment: oh, I should be more attentive. I've updated mock but did not update `expect()` accordingly. You have to validate against mock returned from `useDispatch` not `useDispatch` itself. Updated code in answer.

Comment: I have used like this
```
 expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
    search: '',
    type: '',
    pageNo: 0,
    rowsPerPage: 10,
    order: 'desc',
    orderBy: '',
    paginated: true,
  });

```

giving error like that 

 expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: {"order": "desc", "orderBy": "", "pageNo": 0, "paginated": true, "rowsPerPage": 10, "search": "", "type": ""}
    Received: [Function anonymous]

How can I check my passing params.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202987/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-shubham-singhal).

Comment: I have a similar setup, so when component mounts I will be calling an async action creator. I've just started with the unit testing and I followed this and I'm getting an error.

Comment: @ShubhamSinghal what should be passed as expected action ?

Comment: I get _reactRedux.useDisplatch.mockReturnValue is not a function

Comment: @FernandoZ don't use this method. Instead use `<Provider>` + `redux-mock-store` as I demonstrated below. I'd love to delete answer but unable to(since it's marked as "Accepted")

Answer (score 29):

```
import * as redux from "react-redux";
describe('dispatch mock', function(){    
    it('should mock dispatch', function(){
            //arrange
            const useDispatchSpy = jest.spyOn(redux, 'useDispatch'); 
            const mockDispatchFn = jest.fn()
            useDispatchSpy.mockReturnValue(mockDispatchFn);

            //action
            triggerYourFlow();

            //assert
            expect(mockDispatchFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expectedAction);

            //teardown
            useDispatchSpy.mockClear();
    })
}});
```

From functional component we mock dispatch like above to stop it to execute the real implementation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is how I solved using react testing library:

I have this wrapper to render the components with Provider

```
export function configureTestStore(initialState = {}) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
  );
  const origDispatch = store.dispatch;
  store.dispatch = jest.fn(origDispatch)

  return store;
}

/**
 * Create provider wrapper
 */
export const renderWithProviders = (
  ui,
  initialState = {},
  initialStore,
  renderFn = render,
) => {
  const store = initialStore || configureTestStore(initialState);

  const testingNode = {
    ...renderFn(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          {ui}
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    ),
    store,
  };

  testingNode.rerenderWithProviders = (el, newState) => {
    return renderWithProviders(el, newState, store, testingNode.rerender);
  }

  return testingNode;
}
```

Using this I can call `store.dispatch` from inside the test and check if it was called with the action I want.

```
  const mockState = {
    foo: {},
    bar: {}
  }

  const setup = (props = {}) => {
    return { ...renderWithProviders(<MyComponent {...props} />, mockState) }
  };

  it('should check if action was called after clicking button', () => {
    const { getByLabelText, store } = setup();

    const acceptBtn = getByLabelText('Accept all');
    expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(doActionStuff("DONE"));
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

I see advantages in using actual `<Provider store={store}>`:

- much easier to write tests
- much more readable since just store's data is actually mocked(one mock instead of multiple - and sometimes inconsistent - mocks for `useDispatch` and `useSelector`)

But introducing real store with real reducer(s) and real dispatching looks like overkill to me as for unit testing(but would be ok to integration testing):

- mocking all the server requests might be a huge task
- typically we already have that logic covered with test on per-slice basis

With this in mind have picked `configureStore` from `redux-mock-store` instead `redux` and got next helper(uses Enzyme):

```
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

function renderInRedux(
  children,
  initialData = {}
) {
  let state = initialData;
  const store = (configureMockStore([thunk]))(() => state);
  const wrapper = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
  return {
    /*
    since Enzyme wrappers are readonly, we need retrieve target element in unit test each time after any interaction
     */
    getComponent() {
      return wrapper.childAt(0);
    },
    /*
    set store to any desired config; previous value is replaced;
     */
    replaceStore(newState) {
      act(() => {
        state = newState;
        store.dispatch({ type: dummyActionTypeName }); // just to trigger listeners
      });
      wrapper.update();
    },
    /*
    bridge to redux-mock-store's getActions
     */
    getActions() {
      return store.getActions().filter(({ type }) => type !== dummyActionTypeName);
    },
    /*
    bridge to redux-mock-store's clearActions()
     */
    clearActions() {
      return store.clearActions();
    },
  };
}
```

And example of usage:

```
    const {
      getComponent,
      replaceStore,
    } = renderInRedux(<Loader />, { isRequesting: false });

    expect(getComponent().isEmptyRender()).toBeTruthy();

    replaceStore({ isRequesting: true });
    expect(getComponent().isEmptyRender()).toBeFalsy();
```

But how would it help to avoid mocking server side interaction if we want to test dispatching? Well, by itself it does not. But we can mock and test action dispatching in easy way:

```
import { saveThing as saveThingAction } from '../myActions.js';

jest.mock('../myActions.js', () => ({
  saveThing: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ type: 'saveThing' })
}));

  beforeEach(() => {
  });
....
   const { getComponent, getActions } = renderInRedux(
      <SomeForm />, 
      someMockedReduxStore
   ); 
   getComponent().find(Button).simulate('click');
   expect(getActions()).toContainEqual(saveThingAction());
   expect(saveThingAction).toHaveBeenCalledWith(someExpectedArguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux'

describe('test', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const mockXXXFn = jest.fn()
    const spyOnUseDispatch = jest
      .spyOn(ReactRedux, 'useDispatch')
      .mockReturnValue({ xxxFn: mockXXXFn })

    // Do something ...

    expect(mockXXXFn).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)

    spyOnUseDispatch.mockRestore()
  })
})
```

UPDATE: DO NOT use React Redux hooks API which is strongly coupling with Redux store implementation logic, make it very difficult to test.