# mock useDispatch followed by .then() with jest inside functional component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-functional-component, dispatch

My scenario is just one step ahead of this [existing question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018071/)

I have dispatch fn but with .then() followed by.

Component:

```
const Testing = props => {
const [counterData, setCounterData] = useState(0)
const resData = useSelector(state => state.test)
const dispatch = useDispatch()
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchTestinData())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            setCounterData(prev => prev + 1)
        })
}, [])

return <div>
    Testing component
    <div>
        Result - {resData.title}
    </div>
    <div>
        Counter - {counterData}
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Test file:

```
// const mockDispatch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({json : async () => []})
const mockDispatch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 
Priomise.resolve({title:'tets'}))
jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useDispatch: () => mockDispatch
}))

describe('<Testing />', function () {
    const getComponent = (state) => <Provider store={store}>
        <Testing />
    </Provider>

    it('testing success api', () => {
        // window.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce({title: 'testing title'})
        render(getComponent())
        screen.debug()
        // expect(mockDispatch).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    })

})
```

if am using just jest.fn() getting same error as well as with mock implemntaion.
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRdtO.png)

Something am missing in mock fn implementaion.
Plase help. Searched a lot but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Jest [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/es6-class-mocks#calling-jestmock-with-the-module-factory-parameter) are a bit misleading about the possibility to use previously defined variables in a mock module factory: [that is just not possible](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11862#issuecomment-916683519).

So the solution to your issue is just to move your `mockDispatch` implementation inside the module factory:

```
jest.mock('react-redux',
  () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual('react-redux'),
    useDispatch: () => jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
      Promise.resolve({ title: 'test' }))
  })
)
```

Comment: Awesome man! I searched and post my question on the whole internet,udemy courses and whatnot.
But got a working and valid answer from you. This will help a lot of people.

But i got another common warning because of this solution. As I have setState() inside .then block, so getting waring to use act(). Hoping valid implementation for this too.

Err:
    Warning: An update to Testing inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).
    When testing, code that causes React state updates should be wrapped into act(...):
    act(() => {
      /* fire events that update state */
    });